# Postman Authorization using header parameter working but not with Axios header

Tags: laravel, api, axios, jwt, bearer-token

Laravel Jwt API testing with external Vue app. When I add authorization from dropdown it is working fine. see below

[image]

But same thing is do in Axios(in my vue app) using header config, but does not work and show invalid token. here is the code

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");if (token){axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;}
```

Reposne show invlid token.

I can see the header Authorization is attached in dev tool.

[image]

What I am missing here, help

Comment: Perhaps it is the way you are passing the token as the bearer, are you sure the token have no white-spaces in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check without creating const variable:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") === null) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
}
```